# Service account is missing iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator error when deploying Cloud Function with Eventarc trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I'm trying to deploy a Cloud Function with Eventarc trigger. When deploying, I get the following message:

```
Service account [service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com] is missing the role [roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator].
Pub/Sub needs this role to create identity tokens. For more details, please see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authentication

Bind the role [roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator] to service account [service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com]? (Y/n)?
```

After typing Y, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Service account service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.]
```

I can't find the `service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account anywhere. I looked for it:

1. In the Service Accounts page in IAM
2. In the main IAM page, in the Permissions tab, checking Include Google-provided role grants checkbox
3. In the Permissions tab of the topic in PubSub

I understand that this service account should be created automatically when enabling the PubSub API. and from the docs it looks like PubSubs created after 2021 should have this role in place (mine was created a few days ago), but it looks like for some reason it was not created.
How can I find it or create it, in order to successfully deploy the function?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, here are the problem details and how to solve it.

The problem is that for some reason an associated service account for the PubSub was not created when the PubSub was created. This resulted in no permissions for the PubSub to access some data in the cloud.

The solution is to manually create service account (called also Service Agent) for the PubSub.
This is done with this command in gcloud:

`gcloud beta services identity create --service=pubsub.googleapis.com --project=PROJECT_ID`

After that - grant the Cloud PubSub Service Agent role to the service account, and deploy the function again, it will work.

You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-service-agents).